# How can I add textures to collada file (.dae) using THREE.js?

Tags: three.js, textures, collada

I need to display collada file (.dae) using three.js , i can load model but it display without textures , using this code

```
var loader = new THREE.ColladaLoader( loadingManager );
            loader.options.convertUpAxis = true;
            loader.load( './car.dae', function ( collada ) {

                car = collada.scene;

                car.material = 
     THREE.TextureLoader("../model/car_white.jpg");
```

i tried other codes ,only this code worked for model but without texture 
need your support to add my texture.

Comment: If your textures are inside the collada model then you need to follow the example at https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/examples/webgl_loader_collada.html. If your textures are not referenced directly by the collada model you would need a collada editor (to add them). It would be very hard to add textures to your model from three.js as you would need to compute UV coordinates ... something not very easy for non simple models.

Answer (score 2):

Generally speaking, you can add textures to a model like this:

```
var textureLoader = new THREE.TextureLoader();
var texture = textureLoader.load('../model/car_white.jpg');

loader.load( './car.dae', function ( collada ) {

  collada.scene.traverse(function (node) {
    if (node.isMesh) {
      node.material.map = texture;
    }
  });

});
```

Refer to the documentation for [THREE.Material](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/materials/Material) and [THREE.TextureLoader](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/loaders/TextureLoader) for more information.

> **NOTE:** As @gaitat mentioned in a comment, your texture may not be wrapped correctly on the model if they weren't designed for one another, and if the model isn't very simple. If that's the case, you probably need to add the texture in Blender (or other software) instead, where you can create UVs, and export the result.